# Xamarin Android Debug Install Error

Tags: c#, android, debugging, deployment, xamarin

I am getting this error now

```
Deployment failed because of an internal error: Unexpected install         
output: Segmentation fault
```

when I try to debug my app on a device..

This has come up out of no where, been working on the app for 5 months now and never had this happen..
Friday last week, everything was working fine, today I'm getting this ..

Is this some sort of "Ghost in the machine" stuff? 
Blue Monday?
Or just a sign not to code today ?
lol !

Comment: deleted bin, obj, cleaned project and rebuilt it? ^^

Comment: hmmmm .. Nope still the same ?!?

Comment: Have you uninstalled the app manually on your device? (not via drag and drop. Delete it via `Settings > Apps`.

Comment: Is it possible that it could be the cable ? maybe there is a wire that got torn somehow ? ... only thing I can think of so guessing ..

Comment: yeah did that , and removed the Mono runtimes aswell.. restarted again ..

Comment: Had a look at this one? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/958/problems-debugging-deploying-application

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sven for the link!

```
$ adb shell stop
$ adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio false
$ adb shell start
```

This seemed to fix the problem, no idea why?
If everything, including the device was untouched, then how could something like this work?
But it did, so..

Thanks again Sven !